# Palindrome programming

Tags: c++

the question is

A palindrome is a string that is read the same in both directions, for example, racecar, eye, etc. Write a program in 
that prompts the user to enter a string and uses a recursive function to determine if the given input is a palindrome

i have done this so far but its not working guys :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>// to save string

int isPalindrome(char*str);

int main (void)
{
    int result;
    char str[50];

    printf("\n pls enter string; \n");
    gets(str);
    result = isPalindrome(str);

    if(result ==1) 
    {
        printf("\n input string in a palindrome string ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" not a palindrome");
    }

    getch();

    return 1;
}

int isPalindrome(char*str)
{
    static int length = strlen(str);

    if(length<1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

   if(str[0]=str[lenght - 1])
   {
       length-=2;
   }

   return isPalindrome(str + 1)
}


{
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq] if you haven't already.

Comment: It would help if your example was complete, compilable and runnable! As its stands, there are a few typoed variable names. Also, if you were to use `std::string` you might find your life becomes _much_ easier.

Comment: Uh, also... this is just C. There's not a single bit of C++ in there that I can see. Did you really mean to tag it C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as C++, this approach would work:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool isPalindrome(const std::string& str)
{
    // comparison based on 2 string iterators - a "normal" one
    // and a reversed one
    return std::equal(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), str.begin());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << isPalindrome("racecar") << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << isPalindrome("truck") << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

Comment: +1, `equal()` with `rbegin()` and `begin()` is a wonderful trick!

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as the test function is so small in Stephan's answer, we can simplify it further with lambda syntax ...

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto isPalindrome = [](const std::string& str)->bool{return std::equal(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), str.begin());};
    std::cout << isPalindrome("racecar") << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << isPalindrome("truck") << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

Which would allow you to do some neat stuff like this

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"cat", "racecar", "truck", "1991", "eye", "fish"};

    std::cout << "There are " <<
    count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::string& str)->bool{return std::equal(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), str.begin());})
    << " palindromes in the list";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost everything about this function is broken:

```
int isPalindrome(char*str)
{
    static int length = strlen(str);

    if(length<1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(str[0]=str[lenght - 1])
    {
        length-=2;
    }

    return isPalindrome(str + 1)
}

{
     return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming you've just done a very careless copy and paste. Basically, the `return 0` isn't part of the function scope, so your test *will never return 0*. It will therefore accept all strings as palindromes. And this is even before the fact that your first-and-last character test is typoed and incorrect, too.

Fixing the most glaring bugs:

```
int isPalindrome(char*str)
{
    static int length = strlen(str);

    if(length<1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(str[0]==str[length - 1])
    {
        length-=2;

        return isPalindrome(str + 1)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

results in some code that will at least build, run and give correct results. But it isn't C++!

Comment: +1, the person who asked the question might learn a thing or 2 from this anwser

Comment: I believe that length will only be initialized on the very first call.   Hence, isPalindrome("racecar");  isPalidrome("foo"); won't work, because length will be wrong for the "foo" call.

Comment: @abelenky you are indeed correct. The original code block only attempts to validate a single string before exiting so the single initialisation isn't a problem in that particular example. I've not bothered to do any code restructuring as a) no-one really knows what the OP wants and b) there are some nice pure C++ answers already provided ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line has problems:

```
if(str[0]=str[lenght - 1])
```

First, the variable is `length`, **not** `lenght`.
This alone indicates the code you posted is **not** the code you are actually running.

Secondly, in C an equality comparison is `==`, not a single-equals (which is used for assignment).

Answer (score 0):

You said C++ in the tag, so ..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string input, tupni;
    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    tupni = input;
    std::reverse(tupni.begin(), tupni.end());

    if(tupni==input){
        std::cout << "Is a palindrome" <<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Not a palindrome" <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This uses the `reverse` algorithm from the STL. Always look at the existing algorithms available. There will almost always be something that will help you solve your problem quickly.

The copy of the string here is a little wasteful. For more efficiency, go with the reverse itterator approach suggested by Stephan.

Comment: Could some1 pls tell m what is the type of the code i wrote? is it c++ or c? or which type of code...sorry guys but i am new to c++ and practicing day by day :)